# Equivalent of attachment_fu's "after_attachment_saved" in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, attachment-fu

Migrating from Rails 2 to 3 and I had to ditch attachment_fu.  Other people will probably have the same problem.  One of my models using attachment_fu has an after_attachment_saved method defined, which attachment_fu would call on successful upload.  What is the equivalent for Paperclip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want the `after_post_process` hook.  See the Events section in the documentation here:  https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip